How to determine sample sizes for experiments with ambiguous randomisation units?
I am running an A/B test to compare two bidding strategies in an online auction system, where the goal is to improve Return on Investment (ROI). The two strategies differ in how they bid for impressions and conversions, so the amount spent and the number of conversions are not independent of each other.
Since multiple bids may occur on the same conversion across different auctions (i.e., the same user may be targeted multiple times before converting), I cannot assume that individual auctions are independent. Instead, I'm considering each day as a cluster, where I observe total spend, conversions, and revenue to calculate the ROI for that day.
I want to calculate how many days I need to run this test to detect a significant difference in ROI between the two strategies. Here are the details:

ROI=Revenue/Spend
ROI=SpendRevenue​
Baseline ROI: ROI under the current (fixed) bidding strategy is $ ROI_0 $​.
Target ROI: I expect the new (adaptive) bidding strategy to improve ROI by $δ$ (e.g., 10%).
Cluster size: On average, there are m auctions per day.
Intra-cluster correlation (ICC): I expect the auctions within each day (cluster) to be correlated, but I'm not sure how to estimate this.
Standard deviation: I have estimates of the daily ROI standard deviation for the baseline strategy, $σ_{ROI_0}​$​.

I know that in cluster randomized trials, the number of clusters (days) needed can be calculated using the following formula:
$$
N_{\text{clusters}} = \left( \frac{Z_{\alpha/2} + Z_{\beta}}{\delta_{\text{ROI}}} \right)^2 \times \frac{\sigma_{\text{ROI}_0}^2}{m \left( 1 + (m - 1) \cdot \text{ICC} \right)}
$$
Where:

$ Z_{\alpha/2} $: Critical value for significance level (e.g., 1.96 for 5% significance).
$ Z_{\beta} $: Critical value for power (e.g., 0.84 for 80% power).
$ \delta_{\text{ROI}} $: The minimum detectable difference in ROI (e.g., 10% improvement).
$ m $: The average number of auctions per day.
$ \text{ICC} $: The intra-cluster correlation coefficient.
$ \sigma_{\text{ROI}_0} $: Standard deviation of the baseline ROI.

Questions:

How should I estimate the intra-cluster correlation (ICC) for ROI given that the spend and conversions are intertwined?

Does the formula above seem appropriate for calculating the number of days needed for the test? If not, what adjustments should I consider?


3.What factors should I account for in estimating the standard deviation of daily ROI under the current strategy?
Any guidance on how to approach this calculation or refine these estimates would be greatly appreciated!

"you cannot assume that individual auctions are independent", can you assume each user is independent? day is much larger cluster then user and will harm your experiment power

You can assume that each user is independent, but you don't know how many users. I only have access to the total number of auctions and the total number of impressions, clicks, and conversions. There's no way to infer the number of distinct users (and a 3rd party controls the randomisation process).
